# error in running python program in PyCharmIDE

Tags: python, pycharm

> [Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\MY
> HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe "C:/Users/MY
> HP/PycharmProjects/helloworld/tbjsrton.py"']

whenever I try to run a python program in the PyCharm IDE it is showing this error.
I have installed the python10 files in the default folder recommended by the python setup.

[image]

Comment: I started receiving this error after i reinstalled both Pycharm and python.

Comment: Make sure that you set the environmental variables of the python and create a virtual environment.

Comment: I will try it out, thanks a lot !!!

Comment: oh but how do you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you set the environmental variables of the python and create a virtual environment.
You can edit the configuration and the easy way to do it is by creating a new project and setting the environment as the following:
[image]

or edit the configuration

[image]

or you can add an interpreter as the following

[image]

To set the path of python, find environmental variables and add the path as the following:

[image]